# How to copy file from localhost to remote host in Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have a directory:

```
/users/rolando/myfile
```

I want to copy "myfile" to hostname "targetserver" in directory:

`/home/rolando/myfile`

What is the syntax in the playbook to do this? Examples I found with the `copy` command look like it's more about copying a file from a source directory on a remote server to a target directory on the same remote server.

The line in my playbook .yml I tried that failed:

```
- copy: 
    src='/users/rolando/myfile' 
    dest='rolando@targetserver:/home/rolando/myfile'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) synopsis:

> The `copy` module copies a file on the local box to remote locations.

```
- hosts: targetserver
  tasks:
    - copy:
        src: /users/rolando/myfile
        dest: /users/rolando/myfile
```

Comment: this link is dead.  is there an updated answer for this?

Comment: yes, the copy / ansible.builting.copy module still exists : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html

Comment: above both ansible modules copies on my local server. I am not able to file on remote server. using ansible 2.9

Answer (score 4):

Here is the updated answer. Above answer helps copy files in local machine itself.
This should be easy using remote_src parameter available in [copy module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/copy_module.html#parameter-remote_src)

```
- name: Copy a "sudoers" file on the remote machine for editing
  copy:
    src: /users/rolando/myfile
    dest: /home/rolando/myfile
    remote_src: yes
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... but it does answer my Google query!

Answer (score 0):

From Ansible 2.10 the core modules was reorganized into the namespaces and the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) suggests to use `ansible.builtin.copy`:

```
- hosts: targetserver
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: /users/rolando/myfile
        dest: /users/rolando/myfile
```